# I want an alert box before 10 min in the countdown timer using javascript

Tags: javascript

Code below is to show the timer for session expiry.I wanted to show alerts for the last 10 min and 5 min and 1 min before expiry. Tried many ways but was not successful.

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function countdown(minutes) {
    var seconds = 60;
    var mins = minutes

function tick() {

    var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
    var current_minutes = mins-1
    seconds--;

    counter.innerHTML = 'Remaining Time  for your session to expire is ' +
current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") +     String(seconds);
    if( seconds > 0 ) {
        setTimeout(tick, 1000);
    } else {

        if(mins > 1){

           // countdown(mins-1);   never reach “00? issue solved:Contributed    by Victor Streithorst
           setTimeout(function () { countdown(mins - 1); }, 1000);

        }

    }
}

    tick();
}
 var config = <?php echo json_encode($time4) ?>;
countdown(config);

</script>
```

Comment: `if(minutes == 5) { alert("5 minutes left!"); }` This is difficult?

Comment: I tried with that code before itself...but that wasn't working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add following conditions:

Note: I have moved `mins-1` to a different variable. If you want to use same expression while passing parameter, you will have to compute `mins-1` multiple times.

```js
var newMin = mins - 1;
if (newMin === 1 || newMin === 5 || newMin === 10)
  alert(newMin + " minutes left.");
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/wparsj1n/).

Comment: I am getting it for the first time but again if i try..its not working